# Invoice is not displaying in Invoice tab in admin order view - Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I have created an invoice. But it is not displaying in "Invoice tab".
please find attachment

[image]

Anyone have an idea , why it is not coming?

Comment: I think you invoice is not created properly. check your `sales_flat_invoice_grid` table for that invoice id is in table or not.

Comment: Yes, invoice Id is generating and invoice id also visible in "Comments history tab", but it is not visible in "invoice tab with data".

Comment: can you show your "information tab" screenshot of order view page.

Comment: Yes, please find screenshot https://www.diigo.com/item/image/6aphk/1nbg

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Is showing in Sales -> Invoices grid.?

Comment: No, it is showing in table https://www.diigo.com/item/image/6aphk/pqws

Comment: You created invoice today,then how created_at is "2017-10-10"?

Comment: Actually it was example of old order, but for new invoice same this is coming in table

Comment: Sorry @Ravi varma,I didn't understand. Your `order_increment_id` is ''100001933",But in order view screenshot Increment Id is showing "100002324".This two are different orders so invoice is not mapped to that order.

Comment: sorry for that.
i have created new order please see scrrenshot : https://www.diigo.com/item/image/6aphk/gkdj
and in comment history tab, you can see invoice id : https://www.diigo.com/item/image/6aphk/1b06